# Elasticsearch query_string filter with Fields when not empty string

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, dsl, querydsl

Im trying to build a query_string with elasticsearch DSL, my query is sql style is like this :

```
 SELECT NAME,DESCRIPTION, URL, FACEBOOK_URL, YEAR_CREATION FROM MY_INDEX WHERE FACEBOOK_URL<>'' and ( Match('NAME: sometext OR DESCRIPTION: sometext )) AND YEAR_CREATION > 2000
```

I dont know how to include filter for no empty value for FACEBOOK_URL

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below mapping, sample documents, the request query and response.

Note that I may not have added all the fields but only the concerned fields so as to mirror the query you've added.

### Mapping:

```
PUT facebook
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "description":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "facebook_url":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "year_creation":{
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Docs:

In the below 4 documents, only the `3rd document` mentioned would be something that you would want to be returned.

Docs `1 and 2` have empty values of `facebook_url` while doc `4` does not have the field in the first place at all.

```
POST facebook/_doc/1
{
  "name": "sometext",
  "description": "sometext",
  "facebook_url": "",
  "year_creation": "2019-01-01"
}

POST facebook/_doc/2
{
  "name": "sometext",
  "description": "sometext",
  "facebook_url": "",
  "year_creation": "2019-01-01"
}


POST facebook/_doc/3
{
    "name" : "sometext",
    "description" : "sometext",
    "facebook_url" : "http://mytest.fb.link",
    "year_creation" : "2019-01-01"
}


POST facebook/_doc/4
{
  "name": "sometext",
  "description": "sometext",
  "year_creation": "2019-01-01"
}
```

### Request Query:

```
POST facebook/_search
{
  "_source": ["name", "description","facebook_url","year_creation"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": "sometext"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "description": "sometext"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "facebook_url"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "year_creation": {
              "gte": "2000-01-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "facebook_url": {
              "value": ""
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think the query would be self-explainable.

I have added [Exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query so that if the document *does not have that field*, it would not be appearing the result, however *for empty values* I've added a clause in `must_not`.

Notice that in my design, I've used `facebook_url` as [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type as it makes no sense to have it in text type. For that reason, I've used [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Also note that for date filtering, I've made use of [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html). Do go through the links for more clarification as it is important to understand more on how each of these query works.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.148216,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "facebook",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 2.148216,
        "_source" : {
          "facebook_url" : "http://mytest.fb.link",
          "year_creation" : "2019-01-01",
          "name" : "sometext",
          "description" : "sometext"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Updated Answer:

Change the field of `ANNEE_CREATION` from `integer` to `Date` field as that is the correct type for the Date fields.

You have not applied range query on the date field based on ***your query in question.***

Note that for `must_not` apply the logic on `keyword` field of `facebook` that you have and not on `text` field.

```
{ 
   "query":{ 
      "bool":{ 
         "must":[ 
            { 
               "query_string":{ 
                  "query":" Bordeaux",
                  "fields":[ 
                     "VILLE",
                     "ADRESSE",
                     "FACEBOOK"
                  ]
               }
            },
            { 
               "exists":{ 
                  "field":"FACEBOOK"
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[ 
            { 
               "term":{ 
                  "FACEBOOK.keyword":{               <------ Make sure this is a keyword field 
                     "value":""
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[ 
            { 
               "range":{ 
                  "FONDS_LEVEES_TOTAL":{ 
                     "gt":0
                  }
               }
            },
            { 
               "range":{                              <----- Apply the range query here based on what you've mentioned in question
                  "ANNEE_CREATION":{                  <----- Make sure this is the date field
                    "gte": "2015"                     <----- Make sure you apply correct query parameter in range query
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "from":0,
   "size":8,
   "_source":[ 
      "FACEBOOK",
      "NOM",
      "ANNEE_CREATION",
      "FONDS_LEVEES_TOTAL"
   ]
}
```

As expected only the document having `Id 3` is returned as result.

Comment: Thanks Kamal, but for my scenario its not working i still have documents with empty value here my code :

Comment: Could you share me the mapping details of your index? You can do that by executing `GET index_name/_mapping`. If you could do that and post the mapping details in the question, I can quickly understand what could be going wrong and can provide you with the fix accordingly.

Comment: i use that query : { "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "query_string": { "query": " Bordeaux","fields" : ["VILLE","ADRESSE","FACEBOOK"] } }, { "exists": { "field": "FACEBOOK" } } ], "must_not" :[ { "term": { "FACEBOOK": { "value": "" } } } ], "filter": [ { "range" : {"FONDS_LEVEES_TOTAL" :{"gt": 0}}} , { "match": {"ANNEE_CREATION": "2015"} } ] } } ,"track_total_hits": true, "from": 0, "size": 8 ,"_source": ["FACEBOOK","NOM","ANNEE_CREATION","FONDS_LEVEES_TOTAL"] }     I use ELK 7.3 (mapping all fields text/keyword except ANNEE_CREATION and FONDS_LEVEES_TOTAL as integer

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear about @Kamal's point. You should examine the type of your "FACEBOOK" field, which must be `keyword` type but not `text`.